# Hyperledger Fabric and NodeJS - How to convert buffer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using Hyperledeger Fabric v1.1 and I'm developing a backend in NodeJs.

Using the Fabric NodeJS SDK I can successfully query the blockchain and retrieve the information of the current block.

However, I can't properly convert the hash of the block from the Buffer type.

Below the snippet of the json that I retrieve from the blockchain.

```
currentBlockHash:{
  "buffer": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [8,38,18,32,150,172,137,248,232,203,159,23,44,4,75,29,169,171,120,165,83,22,158,45,93,3,37,120,100,164,229,211,49,194,208,181,26,32,119,47,159,196,237,190,29,24,139,56,212,190,59,126,77,80,76,228,28,171,108,134,241,97,162,190,84,39,240,25,115,135]
  }
}
```

How can I convert this to a normal string in utf-8 in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arraybuffer-to-string` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arraybuffer-to-string).

```
var str = arrayBufferToString(buffer, encoding='utf8')
```